# Determine if input focus is due to autofocus or user interaction

Tags: javascript, html, focus, dom-events, onfocus

I have the first input element of my page taking action in the focus event. However, I only want to do this when the user intentionally manually focuses on the box, either due to clicking, tabbing, etc. I don't want the default autofocus action of the browser to trigger the action.

Is there a way to tell the difference?

Answer (score 2):

Given an `<input>` element with `autofocus` enabled:

```
<input autofocus>
```

... you can use JavaScript to ignore the automatic `focus` event by checking whether the `autofocus` attribute is present. If it is, turn off autofocus, so that all future events will work.

```
const input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('focus', e => {
  // Ignore the first, automatic focus event
  if (e.target.autofocus) {
    e.target.autofocus = false;
    return;
  }

  // ... Handle user-triggered focus events ...
});
```

Comment: `autofocus` is not enabled. It is just the first input field in the DOM, and so it is the default autofocus field. This also feels hacky to use a flag like this, because there are ways that a field might not get focus automatically even if it were to have `autofocus` set.

Comment: When does a field get automatic focus without the `autofocus` attribute? Do you have some code that does that? As to the flag, when does a field with `autofocus` not get automatic focus? (I suppose that would be an issue if multiple fields have that attribute, but I'm not sure why you'd want that.)

Answer (score -2):

autofocus does not trigger the focus event.

Comment: That does not seem to be consistent with what I am seeing.

Comment: @EddiGordo could you please point to where it says that in any docs?